# How to create a nested subquery to be inserted into multiple tables in c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array

i have 3 tables in which i would want the tables to look as follows

Table1

[image]

Table 2 will be the sub categories of table 1

[image]

And Table 3 will store items belonging to table1 and table 2. Not all items in this table will have a subcategory.

Table 3

[image]

just for easier reading this is the structure

[image]

so this is what i tried:
i created a class as follows

```
public class values{
public string code {get;set;}
public List<string> Table1Category { get; set; } = CreateCategory()
private static IEnumerable<string> CreateCatergory()
        {
            return new List<string>
            {
                 "Bedroom",
                 "Balcony",
                 "Kitchen"

            };
        }
}
```

and then i call a method as follows

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(values command)
        {
            foreach (var catergory in command.Table1Category )
            {
                var catergoryGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                Model category = (new Model
                {
                    Name = catergory,
                    Id = catergoryGuid,
                    code= command.code
                });
                await Table1.AddAsync(category);
 
            }
        }
```

this adds my data into table 1 the part i am stuck with is i dont know how to link the items from all tables with each another

Comment: The reason for creating multiple tables in a database is to save memory and not duplicating information.  Table 2 has exactly the same information as table 1 except you added a new column id which is using more memory.  You do not need table 1 if all the info is also in table 2.

Comment: @jdweng then how would i know which one is a subcategory of table 1 items?

Comment: The issue is table 2 contains everything in table 1, so you do not need table 1.  To do it right table one would have two columns 1) Room Name 2) Room ID like Living room, Bedroom, dining room.  Then table 2 would have 1) Room ID [same as table 1] 2) Part Number 3) Description  Table 2 would not have room name because you can lookup the room name from table 1.